# How to automatically print instead of download using vue-html2pdf

Tags: vue.js

I am currently using this package to generate a pdf for my component, does anyone have any ideas on how to get it automatically open the print dialog instead of downloading the pdf?

So I was able to get this working by using the `hasDownloaded="attemptPrint($event)"` prop on vue-html2pdf.

My attemptPrint function is as below:

```
      attemptPrint(blob) {
        let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(url); //opens the pdf in a new tab
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get this working by using the `hasDownloaded="attemptPrint($event)"` prop on vue-html2pdf.

My attemptPrint function is as below:

```
      attemptPrint(blob) {
        let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(url); //opens the pdf in a new tab
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this there is a property called: preview-modal, which shows a window with the result of the export.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-html2pdf#props